# Ajax Call to save images in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I Having issue in uploading images, I want to upload four images individually in MVC as shown in below figure(Please click on "Upload Image File" link to show the image), If we choose one file the particular picture wants to save and it wants to show the preview with proper file name as heading. please help me.. thanks in Advance

[Upload Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRqXV.jpg)

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. The title says AJAX but your question doesn't say how you want to use AJAX. What have you tried to far?

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear but this is a good solution for uploading in MVC using Ajax:

**File Upload HTML**

```
<div style="display:none;">
   <img id="image" alt="" src="" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div id="fileUpload">
<span>Choose Image</span>
<input id="txtUploadFile" type="file" name="files" class="upload" />
</div>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_UploadPartial.cshtml")
```

**Create a Partial View or added to HTML**

**if you create a partial view for below code can use it anywhere on site, or create a .js file either is way will work well.

```
<script>

var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$('#txtUploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/User/UploadFile/' + model,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#image').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")' + result.fileName);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller Method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadFile(string id)
    {
        var path = "";
        var fileExtension = "";
        var fileName = "";

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                if (id != "null") 
                {
                   //do bits, save to DB etc./..

                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new { fileName = fileName });
    }
```

**Explanation**

The file upload html with `id="image"` is for when you select a image from your directory after pressing the txtUploadFile input, then the partial view or js file or inline script, depending on approach taken will fire the onchange function: `$('#txtUploadFile').on('change', function (e)` this will do a ajax call to your method in your controller - you can do all your logic like saving to the database ect... from here.

The controller function is then returning the fileName to the success function of the ajax call, assuming you have saved the image somewhere you can then use result.fileName, or whatever to get your image:

```
 $('#image').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")' + result.fileName);
```

As you can see the nested image attribute in the file upload HTML is being changed to the newly uploaded image.

Hope this helps.